# Squeryl clauses (from, select, like, where) are not working in intellij

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, squeryl

I have been trying to get the IDE project to recognize the clauses used by Squeryl. I have add the Squeryl*.jar to my project dependencies yet still I have to import the classes for clause "From" to be used. More specifically I had to extend objects with "import org.squeryl.dsl.boilerplate.FromSignatures" just to make "from" work. That was a weird still viable solution but commands "like/select" cant bee imported.. What is going on? I even tryed implementing the select method..

```
    def select[R](r: =>R): R

    object ExternalVendor extends FromSignatures{
      def findAll = tx {
        from(vendors)(s => select(s)) map(s => s) }

      def select[R](r: =>R): R
      //def select[QueryYield[_R]](r: =>QueryYield[_R]): QueryYield[_R]
    }
```

until it gave me problems with "R" saying select(s) not expected type "QueryYield[_R]"
Please help..

Code:

```
   package object models {
              implicit val transactionFailures: Table[TransactionFailure] = LowkeySchema.transactionFailures
              implicit val vendors: Table[ExternalVendor] = LowkeySchema.vendors
              implicit val products: Table[Product] = LowkeySchema.products
            }

            trait Model[A] extends KeyedEntity[Long] { this: A =>
              val id: Long = 0
              def save(implicit table: Table[A]): Either[Throwable, String] = {
                tx {
                  try {
                    table.insert(this)
                    Right("Domain object is saved successfully")
                  } catch {
                    case exception: Throwable => Left(exception)
                  }
                }
              }
            }

            abstract class ExternalVendor(val name: String, val url: String) extends Model[ExternalVendor]

            object ExternalVendor extends FromSignatures{
              def findAll = tx {
                from(vendors)(s => select(s)) map(s => s) }
              //def select[QueryYield[_R]](r: =>QueryYield[_R]): QueryYield[_R]
            }

            abstract class Product(val description: String,
                          val vendorName: String,
                          val basePrice: Double,
                          val plusPercent: Double)
              extends Model[Product] {
              def calculatePrice = basePrice + (basePrice * plusPercent / 100)
            }

            object Product extends FromSignatures{
              def findByDescription(description: String): Option[Product] =
                tx {
                  products.where(p => p.description like description).headOption
                }
            }
```

Comment: I am using Squeryl_0.9.5. To fix the clause problem in intellij I used PrimitivetypeMode `import org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode._` I dont recieve any syntax errors for clauses like/where/from/etc.. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on this could stand to be improved.  In Squeryl 0.9.5, for typical use, you want to:

```
import org.squeryl._
import PrimitiveTypeMode._
```

The latter import will bring in most of what you need.

In Squeryl 0.9.6 `PrimitiveTypeMode` is deprecated and you would define your own EntryPoint object that you would import from instead.

Comment: If you are using 0.9.6, you can find more information on the deprecation of `PrimitiveTypeMode` here: http://squeryl.org/0.9.6.html

Comment: The fix for the clause problem in intellij was fixed using import org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode._

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've read the [getting started](http://squeryl.org/getting-started.html) section in squeryl's documentation.
After set up, the imports from one of the [examples](https://github.com/max-l/Squeryl/blob/master/src/test/scala/org/squeryl/test/musicdb/MusicDb.scala) should be sufficient:

```
import org.squeryl._
import adapters._
import dsl._
import dsl.ast.{RightHandSideOfIn, BinaryOperatorNodeLogicalBoolean}
import framework._
```